# Gibt es im Deutschen Reste von anderen grammatischen Fällen als den vier üblichen?

Tags: grammatical-case

Ich habe mal gehört, dass das "Hause" in "zu Hause" ein Lokativ ist.

Gibt es noch andere Überbleibsel von ungewöhnlichen grammatischen Fällen im Deutschen?

---

Does German contain relics of other grammatical cases than the four usual ones?

I have heard that "Hause" in "zu Hause" (=at home) is a locative.

Are there any other residues of unusual grammatical cases in German?

Comment: Uh... gute Frage. Es gibt generell diese Form mit "zu" (zu Hause, zu Pferde, Tische, etc.) aber ansonsten fällt mir nicht so richtig was ein.

Comment: Was meinst Du mit **ungewöhlichen** Fällen?

Comment: Ist _auf dem Lande_ auch ein Lokativ?

Comment: Wie im Titel erkenntlich, meine ich damit Fälle, die nicht erster bis vierter Fall sind. In anderen Sprachen sind das etwa Lokativ und Vokativ.

Comment: Ausgezeichnete Frage (+1)

Comment: Ist dann `in die Schulden` ein Ökonomitiv? :)

Comment: Locative and directive are no grammatical cases per se. For example in Latin and in German, the locative and directive are the dative and accusative : Ich gehe in die Küche / Ich bin in der Küche. In horto sum / Eo in hortum.

Comment: Isn't the ablative in Latin generally used as a locative? As some sort of intrumentalis-locative mixture? The forms look often the same as dative, but it's a distinct case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Middle High German used to have traces of an *Instrumental* case, used or discernible only with neutral nouns after prepositions like *von* und *zu* (*ze*) instead of dative. It would give *von diu* instead of *von dëm* (*diu* was the form for the modern *die*).  It seems to have been assimilated completely into dative.

I have not found traces of its use in my documentation in Modern High German, so I believe the answer to the OP's question is no.

EDIT: I believed to have an example of Middle High German instrumental to show but it was a mistake with a plural form.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "von der"? My Middle High German is a bit rusty, but if you start out with *von diu* which I have only ever seen together with a feminine word, then the correct dative would be *von der* (with or without weird e).

Answer (score 15):

In der [indogermanischen Ursprache](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indogermanische_Ursprache) gab es sehr wahrscheinlich den **Vokativ** (auch Anredefall). Darunter versteht man ein spezielle Form eines Nomens, die verwendet wird, um jemanden direkt anzusprechen oder anzurufen.

Dazu im [Wikipedia-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokativ#Deutsch):

> Auch Sprachen, welche keinen morphologischen Vokativ aufweisen, können vokativische Strukturen in ihrer Nominalphrase ausbilden.
>
> Dies ist etwa im Deutschen der Fall, wo im Vokativ der Nullartikel gesetzt wird: Da ein Appellativum wie z.B. Gast in einer Prädikatphrase (also einem Satz mit Verb) für gewöhnlich nicht ohne Artikel steht (außer vor als), ergibt sich aus der artikellosen Verwendung (bzw. der Verwendung mit Nullartikel) eine Vokativphrase, welche üblicherweise mit einem Adjektivattribut angereichert wird. Dieses Attribut begleitet das Kopfnomen stets in seiner unbestimmten Form: Ø lieber Gast!
>
> In der süddeutschen Umgangssprache und in den oberdeutschen Dialekten ist diese Art der Vokativphrase viel häufiger, da hier auch Eigennamen von Personen in der Prädikatphrase den bestimmten Artikel mit sich führen: Das ist der Peter. Aber: Lieber Peter!

Comment: So habe ich das bisher nicht gesehen.

Comment: Die Frage ist, ob es einen Fall geben kann, der in keiner Flexion erkennbar ist

Answer (score 13):

"Zu Hause" is a case of the **"Dativ-e"**:

It used to be that *e* was appended to the dative singular of nouns whose genitive singular ends in "es", some of which has carried over into everyday speech:

- Am eigenen Leibe
- Im diesem Sinne

In addition to its idiomatic use this is still very common in legal texts, but it's not a different case. Similarly, nouns ending in *e* got an *n* appended to them (*in der Hütten* - which is still standard Austro-Bavarian), and female nouns ending in *er* got an extra *n* (*auf der Leitern*).

An argument could also be made that we are drifting towards losing the genitive and the dative over time. Take for instance a sentence like "Ich nahm mich seiner an", which is now uncommon.

Comment: Es gibt auch den versteinerten Genitiv, wie z.B. "der Erlkoenig hat mir ein Leids getan".

Answer (score 5):

**Das steht in jedem Lehrbuch:**

Wer? Was? - erster Fall (Nominativ)

> Wer sitzt im grünen Auto? Hans sitzt im grünen Auto.
>   Was ist in dieser Suppe? Salz ist in dieser Suppe.

Wessen? - zweiter Fall (Genitiv)

> Wessen Schuh ist das? Das ist Manitus Schuh. oder: Das ist der Schuh des Manitu.

Wem? - dritter Fall (Dativ)

> Wem habe ich das zu verdanken? Das hast du deinen Eltern zu verdanken.

Wen? - vierter Fall (Akkusativ)

> Wen hat der Gärtner vergiftet? Der Gärtner hat die Gräfin vergiftet.

---

**Aber da wird's knifflig:**

Die folgenden Beispiele werden im Deutschen mit Hilfe einer Präposition und einem der vier "normalen" Fälle gebildet. Es handelt sich also jeweils um eigene, feststehende Konstruktionen. In anderen Sprachen gibt es dafür ebenfalls eigene Konstruktionen, die aber in den Rang eines Falls (Kasus) erhoben sind.

Wo? - das ist in vielen Sprachen der Lokativ

> Wo ist Anna? Anna ist im Haus. (im = in dem) [in + Dativ]

Wohin? - Allativ

> Wohin gehst du? Ich gehe zum Ausgang. (zum = zu dem) [zu + Dativ]

Womit? - Instrumentalis

> Womit hast du dieses Loch gegraben? Ich habe das Loch mit einer Schaufel gegraben. [mit + Dativ]

Wann? - Temporalis

> Wann ist Lisa heimgekommen? Lisa ist um 18:23 heimgekommen. [um + ? Dativ?]
>   Wann wurde Florian geboren? Florian wurde am 19.4.1982 geboren. [am + ? Dativ?]

Vokativ (Wie fragt man nach dem Vokativ?)

> Sehr geehrter Herr Maier, wie geht es Ihnen? [sehr geehrte(r) + Nominativ]

Ich denke, diese Liste ließe sich beliebig fortführen.

---

Noch eine Anmerkung, gehört nicht mehr 100%ig zum Thema:
Einige deutsche Dialekte verwenden andere Fälle als die hochdeutsche Sprache. Meine "Muttersprache" ist ein oststeirischer Dialekt (ein Dialekt aus der Familie der donaubairischen Dialekte), den ich heute aber kaum noch spreche. In diesem Dialekt gibt es keinen Genitiv. Alles, was im Hochdeutschen mit einem Genitiv gesagt wird, wird in diesem Dialekt durch den Dativ und ein Personalpronom ausgedrückt.

> Hochdeutsch: Wessen Tasche ist das? Das ist Martins Tasche.
>   Dialekt (mit hochdeutschen Vokabeln): Wem seine Tasche ist das? Das ist dem Martin seine Tasche.
>   Dialekt (mit Dialekt-Vokabeln): Wem sei Toschn is des? Des is m Martin sei Toschn.

Dafür gibt es im selben Dialekt noch Reste des Duals, die es in dieser Form im Hochdeutschen nicht mehr gibt:

> Singular: Griaß di! - (ich) grüße dich!
>   Dual: Griaß enk! - (ich) grüße euch! (Wenn man ein Paar begrüßt, nicht aber für zwei Einzelpersonen verwendbar)
>   Plural: Griaß aich! - (ich) grüße euch! (Für mehr als zwei Personen und auch für zwei Einzelpersonen die kein Paar sind)

Comment: zu behaupten dass "Martinsei" weniger genitiv sei als "Martins" ist absurd. Nur weil s an Fugenlaut /m/ neihmogelt hot.

Comment: Was für ein Martinsei? Wovon redest du? Und warum holst du ein 9 Jahre altes Posting aus dem Grab?

Answer (score 3):

Ich denke nicht, dass *Hause* in *zu Hause* in einem Lokativ steht. Ich gehe eher davon aus, dass du 'Ich geh Heim' gemeint hast. Dort fehlt die Präposition, was ein Hinweis auf eine alte Fallform sein könnte. 'Alte' Fallformen sind immer dort zu vermuten, wo Präpositionen unterlassen werden.

In Schweizer Dialekten gibt es dies durchaus.

Beispiele:

> *Deutsch:* Das Zuhause, Heim. Ich gehe nach Hause. Ich bin zu Hause.
>   *Berndeutsch:* Ds Heim, Dahei. I ga *Hei*. I bi *Deheime*.

Die Formen *Hei* und *Daheime* entalten Richtungs- bzw. Ortsinformationen ohne Nutzung von Präpositionen. Die Fälle könnte man als Illativ bzw. Inessiv bezeichnen.

Comment: Im Saarländischen gibt es das übrigens auch: "Ich geh hemm." oder auch "Ich bin dehemm". Wobei "das Zuhause" einfach "dehemm" ist.

Comment: *Heimgehen* ist Hochdeutsch (genauso wie *heimkehren*, *heimkommen*, *heimreisen*). Hierbei ist *heim-* ein Präfix, kein Nomen. Auch "daheim" findet sich im Duden und im Wiktionary, als Adverb und kleingeschrieben, begleitet von dem Vermerk "besonders süddeutsch, österreichisch, schweizerisch".

Answer (score 3):

For me, more interesting than relics of ancient cases is the creation of new cases. It seems to me that "zu mir [destination]" as in "zu mir nach Hause" (to my place), "zu mir ins Bett" (to my bed), "zu mir ins Hotel" (to my hotel), "zu mir ins Büro" (to my office), "zu mir ins Heimat" (to my hometown) and so on is a very productive pattern to mention a place in relation to an entity that is related to a person. When an entity that is related to a person is not the relatum of a location, it is normally represented as "meine Wohnung" (my place), "mein Bett" (my bed) and so on. So, I would say that "bei mir" in "bei mir zu Hause" and "zu mir" in "zu mir nach Hause" are nowadays some sort of possessive personal pronoun respectively in the locative and allative forms.

Comment: "Zu mir ins  Heimat"? I have never heard it and it sounds utterly wrong.

Comment: @Ludi, you got the wrong gender. *Zu mir in die Heimat*, colloquially *inne Heimat* and comversely *komm zumir ins Bett* are so perfectly felicit that I keep arguing *ins* corresponds to Engl. *into*. Point in case, idiomatic *Komm du mir nach Hause* ohne *zu* is constructed like *komm mir ins Bette*, although the latter would be indeed less likely to be heared on average.

Comment: @vectory Not me! I am a native speaker. The author of the above got it wrong! I just pointed to the mistake. :(

Answer (score 2):

Die Formulierung *auf Erden* aus dem *Vater unser* dürfte noch ein Beispiel für den Lokativ sein.

Comment: cf. the answer by Stefano Palazzo